# Solve $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}= 45$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this equation:

$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}= 45$

I started:
$$n^2+n= 90$$

What do I do next?

Comment: Excuse me, but did you divide both sides by $2$, or did you multiply both sides by $2$?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire: What is $2 \times 45$?

Comment: @SimpleArt What was I thinking? I divided by 2 instead of multiplying... I'll fix it

Comment: The answer should be $9$ and $-10$.

Comment: @Moo I fixed that mistake. I still don't know how to solve it though

Comment: Rewrite it as $n^2+n-90=0$.  Then think to yourself, what two numbers that multiply to $90$ also add up to $1$?  Going through the list of factors, we see that $-9$ and $10$ work.  So then you get $(n-9)(n+10)=0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$n^2+n=90$ would be the correct starting point as each side is multiplied by 2.

As for next steps:

$n^2+n-90=0$

$\iff n^2+10n-9n-90=0$

$\iff n(n+10)-9(n+10)=0 $

$\iff (n+10)(n-9)=0$

Thus, $n$ is either 9 or -10.

Comment: It is times like these that make me smile for grouping techniques.

Answer (score 3):

Your equation is

$n(n+1)=90$

$=1\times90$

$=2\times45$

$=3\times30$

$=5\times18$

$=6\times15$

$=9\times10$

so $n=9$  or by opposite $n=-10$.

Comment: Interesting, why did you try to find the lowest divisor? What logic did you use?

Comment: i look for two consecutive divisors

Comment: @Masacroso just a typo as you know

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're solving for n.
Firstly, you didn't complete that step correctly. 
Multiplying both sides by 2 would give $n^2 + n = 90$.
 Subtracting 90 from both sides, $n^2 + n - 90 = 0$. 
Factoring gives $(n+10)(n-9)=0$ 
Therefore, the solutions are $n=9,n=-10$.

Answer (score 0):

$n^2+n=90$

We can write this as-

$n^2+n-90=0$

Now, it is in the quadratic equation form, .i.e., $ax^2+bx+c=0$

Factor out the resulting equation, break $n$ into two terms $10n-9n$

$$n^2+10n-9n-90=0$$
Take $n$ common from first two terms and $-9$ from last two terms-
$$n(n+10)-9(n+10)=0$$
$$(n-9)(9+10)=0$$
$n-9=0\;\implies n=9$

$n+10=0\;\implies n=-10$

Answer (score 0):

@Abdallah has already given an answer that doesn't involve solving a quadratic. My answer (at least the second way) is along the same lines, but maybe slightly more "optimised".

First way. Observe that the LHS is the exact formula for the $n$th triangular number. If you already know the first few terms of the [sequence](https://oeis.org/A000217), you'll immediately be able to come up with the solution $n=9$. Also, if you keep in mind that there is a "mirror" sequence to the triangular numbers for the negative integers, albeit shifted by one, you'll be able to deduce the second solution $n=-10$.

Second way. Let's say you're not all that familiar with the triangular number sequence. Now you can follow Abdallah's method. However, instead of starting at $1$, you should start at $9$ and work backwards. This is because $n^2 + n$ is close to $n$ for larger $n$. So knowing $n^2 < 90$, you can look at the highest square that isn't greater than $90$, and that's $81$. By taking its square root, you have your starting value. In this case, you hit paydirt with the first guess.